# Jenkins: Checkstyle, PMD, Copy-paste-detector reports

Tags: php, jenkins, report, checkstyle

I'm totally new to jenkins and don't know how to create the QA reports. 
I use jenkins with checkstyle, PMD and a copy-paste-detector for PHP. The build runs and completed successful. The output of the console is:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 31 seconds
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #54
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd.xml
[PMD] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #54
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
[DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
[DRY] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #54
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Found 81 classes in 23 packages
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If I look in my build directory, there are the logs for the copy-paste and pmd tool. But checkstyle is missing.

My build file is from this tutorial: [jenkins-php tutorial](http://jenkins-php.org/)

In my job configuration in the post-build actions are all tools listed. BUT there is shown an error I can't resolve. In the post-build actions I have to say where the output file are generated. So for checkstyle I have

```
build/logs/checkstyle.xml
```

But below there is the error message
**build/logs/checkstyle.xml not found: 'build' exists, but not build/logs/checkstyle.xml **

The same with PMD and cops paste. In the overview after an successful build, it tells me, that there were no warnings found. Rhe created log files contain warnings.

So how can I make jenkins to use the created report files?

**EDIT**

Following the checkstyle lines of my build.xml

```
<target name="phpcs" description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="phpcs">
   <arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/project"/>
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs-ci" description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
  <exec executable="phpcs" output="/dev/null">
   <arg value="--report=checkstyle"/>
   <arg value="--report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml"/>
   <arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/project"/>
  </exec>
 </target>
```

If I run phpcs manual I get this:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1 in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PEAR/Sniffs/Functions/FunctionCallSignatureSniff.php on line 186
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpcs:0
PHP   2. PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process() /usr/bin/phpcs:37
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer->process() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php:558
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer->processFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:504
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer->_processFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1258
PHP   6. PHP_CodeSniffer_File->start() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1380
PHP   7. PEAR_Sniffs_Functions_FunctionCallSignatureSniff->process() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:490
PHP   8. PEAR_Sniffs_Functions_FunctionCallSignatureSniff->processMultiLineCall() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PEAR/Sniffs/Functions/FunctionCallSignatureSniff.php:113
```

Comment: Post your checkstyle configuration lines from build.xml

Comment: I have added the lines. Sorry

Comment: The file is only generated when the job builds. Do you have the checkstyle warnings link on the build page? Do you have php-ci defined in a antcall?

Comment: php-ci is not defined as antcall but phpcs-ci. But there is no link with warnings

Comment: Try running the phpcs command manually and see if it outputs any errors

Comment: This is weired. I Added the console log to the question

Comment: Might be a bug. Check if you have the latest PHP_CodeSniffer package